# Mscorcfg.msc .net Configuration Tools problem

Tags: .net, configuration

I'm trying to run Microsoft's .NET Framework Configuration Tool (Mscorcfg.msc). I have Visual Studio 2008 installed. I also have the following installed on my PC:

- Microsoft .Net Framework v1.0.3705
- Microsoft .Net Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2
- Microsoft .Net Framework 3.0 Service Pack 2
- Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 SP1
- Microsoft .Net Framework v4.0.30319

I'm not sure why, but I can't start "Mscorcfg.msc" the usual way (as suggested in the
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc(VS.80).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc.aspx URL). I looked for "Mscorcfg.msc" on my PC and found only 1 occurence (in the C:\WINDOWS\ServicePackFiles\i386 folder). When I double-click on the .msc file in Windows Explorer, I get the  "MMC could not 
create the snap-in." message. What should I do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [CASPOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28VS.80%29.aspx) instead. Personally I was under the impression that we've had to use CASPOL since .net 2.0

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssdk/thread/4762ce1e-c4a2-4315-8274-ee3a3e14ad13):

> It is removed in Windows SDK since
>   Windows SDK 6.0a (the version shipped
>   with VS 2008). You can use the caspol
>   utility in .Net instead.
>
> If you really need it, get the .Net
>   2.0 SDK (I know, 354MB download). It is also included in Visual Studio 2005
>   and earlier Windows SDKs like the
>   Windows SDK 6.0 (The Update for
>   Windows Vista version). You may want
>   to try a web install of Windows SDK
>   and see if you can only install .Net
>   SDK tools to save some bandwidth.